# can html5 footer be used on this way?

Tags: html, markup

I am designing a blog and this is the markup that I am using - showing just the article snippet as I am sure for the rest

```
<article>
    <header>
        <h2>this is the posts title</h2>
        <footer>
           <p>by aurel kurtula on <time>21:21pm</time></p> <ul><li>tag1</li><li>tag2</li><li>tag3</li></ul>
        <footer>
     <section>Here is the body of the article</section>
</article>
```

So my question is should I use footer in that way? and I am assuming that the `<section>` is right to used for the body of the article, or is it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think your code is right. You only have an opening <header> tag without a closing tag, and the <footer> is inside the <header>

Comment: the <header> and <footer> tags are meant to be used as the page header and footer respectively, so this will not work

Comment: @Gigi - No, they're not. They are sectioning elements that can be used to convey a relatively wide range of semantics. They can apply to sections of pages, not pages as a whole. See the specification (e.g. `header` element: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-header-element)

Comment: @james, you are right. i must read the specs more carefully next time

Comment: About the closing header, sorry that was a typing error, where as the <header> and <footer> being only for the beginning and end, I am sure that is not right, I guess, the problem I want to ask was, can I have the footer, in side of the header, or at least right underneath the header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say your structure is fine, as long as you are closing the [`header`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-header-element) tag which you don't appear to be doing in the example code. Since:

> A header element is intended to usually contain the section's heading
>   (an h1–h6 element or an hgroup element)

You should close the `header` after your `h2`:

```
<article>
    <header>
        <h2>this is the posts title</h2>
    </header>
    <footer>
       <p>by aurel kurtula on <time>21:21pm</time></p> <ul><li>tag1</li><li>tag2</li><li>tag3</li></ul>
    <footer>
    <section>Here is the body of the article</section>
</article>
```

It may seem strange to use an element named [`footer`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-footer-element) in the middle of the `article`, but there is nothing wrong with that:

> The footer element represents a footer for its nearest ancestor
>   sectioning content or sectioning root element. A footer typically
>   contains information about its section such as who wrote it, links to
>   related documents, copyright data, and the like.
>
> ...
>
> Footers don't necessarily have to appear at the end of a section,
>   though they usually do.

This means the `footer` in question should apply to the `article` element, not the `section`. If for example you were to have multiple `section` elements per `article`, and each required a separate `footer`, those `footer` elements should probably appear as descendants of their respective `section`.

Comment: this is great, thanks. the fact that I did not close the header was a typing error. I meant to and im my example I had the footer within header, thanks for the clarification